# Implementing CastleWindsor with Model View Presenter (MVP)

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, mvp

I would like to implement CastleWindsor with the MVP pattern, but I keep getting an 'Object Reference Not Set to an Object reference on the Presenter when the repository is called to obtain some data.

This is how I did it and I am wondering if there is anything wrong, so please let me know if you can:

## Presenter:

```
public class CategoryPresenter
{
    ICategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    ICategoryView categoryView;

    public CategoryPresenter(ICategoryView _categoryView, ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository)
    {
        categoryView = _categoryView;
        categoryRepository = _categoryRepository;
    }

    //public CategoryPresenter(ICategoryView _categoryView) : this (_categoryView, new CategoryRepository())
    //{ }

    public CategoryPresenter(ICategoryView _view)
    {
        categoryView = _view;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetActiveCategories()
    {
      return  categoryRepository.GetActiveCategories();
    }
}
```

## IoC Class:

```
public  static class IoC
{
    public static IWindsorContainer windsorContainter { get; set; }
}
```

## IoCConfig Class:

class IoCConfig
    {

```
    public static IWindsorContainer RegisterCastleWindsorContainer()
    {
        IWindsorContainer windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer()
        .Install(new RepositoryInstaller())

        IoC.windsorContainter = windsorContainer;

        return windsorContainer;
    }
```

}

## Installer Class:

```
public class RepositoryInstaller: IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<ICategoryRepository>().ImplementedBy<CategoryRepository>).LifestyleTransient());

    }
}
```

Finally in Global.ascx file I am doing this at App_Start:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        // Code that runs on application startup
        IoCConfig.RegisterCastleWindsorContainer();
    }
```

With this, the error message is as said above; the error happens at the presenter's method: GetActiveCategories();

As you see at no where in code I invoke the resolve method on the container.

Please let me know if if you have any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Why does your presenter have 2 constructors? What happens if you remove the one with one parameter?

Comment: Hi Steve, I am using the constructor with two parameters to run integration tests using Moq, which requires mocking abstract interfaces.

Comment: I have removed the constructor with two parameters as you said, and I did this on the CategoryPresenter:

 ICategoryRepository categoryRepository = IoCConfig.Resolve<ICategoryRepository>() ;

In IoCConfig Class I did this: 

        private static IWindsorContainer windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        public static T Resolve<T>()
        {
            try
            {
                return windsorContainer.Resolve<T>(); //.Resolve(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

Comment: I then had this exception:

No component for supporting the service DataLayer.model.ICategoryRepository was found

Comment: The constructor with a single parameter (view) is required when calling the presenter on the view (aspx or ascx); I cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this to the **IoC Class**

```
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        try
        {
            return windsorContainer.Resolve<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

And then add this to the presenter:

```
   ICategoryRepository categoryRepository = IoC.Resolve<ICategoryRepository>();
   ICategoryView categoryView = IoC.Resolve<ICategoryView>();
```